# client roles haven`t assigned during creating new user in Keycloak

Tags: java, api, curl, keycloak, keycloak-services

Im tried to create new user with clients role.
I have client roles:
- Admin
- Operator
- Manager

And during creating user I want to assign user a client role

my curl:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer token' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://localhost.com/auth/admin/realms/realm/users' --data '{
  "username": "test301@qqq.bbb",
  "enabled": true,
  "firstName": "",
  "lastName": "",
  "email": "test301@qqq.bbb",
  "credentials": [
    {
      "type": "password",
      "value": "qq",
      "temporary": false
    }
  ],
  "clientRoles": {
    "suppression": [
      "Admin"
    ]
  }
}'
```

User have created successfully, but role have not assigned.
Also I want to do this in one request

Comment: have u found the answer on how to do this in one step?

Comment: Did you found the reason?

Answer (score 4):

This is not the correct way to assign roles to the user.
It is a step by step process- 
Step 1 - Create a user in keycloak.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer token' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://localhost.com/auth/admin/realms/realm/users' --data '{.....
```

Step 2 - Then use a different API to map this user to a certain client-role.

```
POST /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{client}
```

For the complete spec of this API, You can search for this API in Keycloak ADMIN API docs. Here's the link
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.0/rest-api/index.html
and search for "Add client-level roles to the user role mapping"

Comment: why a such simple thing have to be in two process

Comment: @aswzen its keycloak, implicit complexity dna, why surprised?

Answer (score 2):

After reading this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60814057/577131

- Create new group (mine is "admin-group")
- Add Role mapping for the role you want every user
  on this group will get this Role.

When using create a new user POST I added this to the user

```
"groups" : [
    "admin-group"
]
```

The user added to this group and gets the role mapped to this group